# Black screen on mac mini dual screen

Tags: display, mac-mini, screen

So I have the new mac mini 2018 and I have a dual screen setup. 1 is connected via display port the other via HDMI. My main display is the one connected via the display port. However, I have this issue on startup where my main screen is just black and the second monitor with just a background image and no login screen. I have to turn one of the screens off to get the login screen. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: If you log in first, then connect the second screen, what happens?

Comment: Everything is alright after login. It's just the booting with both connected.

Comment: Is it possible for you to swap the plugs for the monitor, either directly or with an adaptor?